# Prove $\sin(x)< x< \tan(x)$ when $0< x < \cfrac{\pi}2$ using only geometry/trigonometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Archimedes used the fact that

$\sin(x)< x< \tan(x)$ when $0< x < \cfrac{\pi}2$

to prove that the perimeter of a polygon inscribed in a circle is less than the circumference of the circle. Similarly, he used this to show that the perimeter of a polygon circumscribed about a circle exceeds the circumference of the circle. I want to get some idea as to how Archimedes proved the above result.

Comment: Maybe just plot the graph?

Comment: Look at $f(x)=\sin x-x$ and $g(x)=x-\tan x$.
Using calculus it's easy to see these inequalities are true:  $f'(x) \lt 0$ and $g'(x) \lt 0$ for $x\lt \frac {\pi}2$, with $f(0)=g(0)=0$...

Comment: Archimedes had techniques equivalent to modern day calculus...  but i have no idea how he established these inequalities...  Remember he was one of the four greatest ever. (Euler,  Gauss and Newton being the other three...)

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1536080/291201) for example.

Comment: @ChrisCuster - "Archimedes had techniques equivalent to modern day calculus", really? care to back that statement up?

Comment: I'm referring to his use of the "method of exhaustion ", if nothing else. .. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_exhaustion

Comment: @nbubis. Maybe a more accurate statement would be that he had _begun_ to discover the principles of calculus...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following triangles in the unit circle:
[image]

We know the following:
$\overline{XY} =\overline{XZ} = 1$, $\overline{XV} = \cos\theta$, $\overline{ZV} = \sin\theta$, $\overline{WY} = \tan\theta$. Now, the area of the triangle $\Delta XZY$ is obviously $\frac{1}{2}\sin\theta$. The area of the sector of the unit circle containing $\Delta XZY$ is $\frac{1}{2}\theta$. Finally, the area of $\Delta XWY$ is $\frac{1}{2}\tan\theta$. Since $\Delta XWY$ contains the sector, which contains $\Delta XZY$, we have:
$$\frac{1}{2}\sin\theta < \frac{1}{2}\theta < \frac{1}{2}\tan\theta$$
It is easy to go from this to 
$$\sin\theta < \theta < \tan\theta$$

Comment: Thanks! May I ask you how did you produce this image? I'm trying to find a good way to produce mathematical diagrams.

Comment: I used the TikZ package for LaTeX