# How can I prove the formula of the area of a circle without $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin x/x = 1$ and integrals?

Tags: limits

My main claim is to prove $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin x/x = 1$. So I drew a circular sector and some triangles so I could get the following formula from its areas:
$\sin (x / 2)  <  x / 2  <  \tan (x / 2)$.
But I think I can prove that the area of a circular sector is $x / 2$ only from $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin x/x = 1$ or integrals. Am I wrong? How can I prove that the area of a circle is $\pi r^2$ without integrals and $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin x/x = 1$?

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to prove it using curve lengths and perimeters instead of areas, see for example my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1536080/291201) for a sketch of such proof.

Comment: [Here](https://thatsmaths.com/2017/07/27/who-first-proved-that-c-d-is-constant/) and [here](http://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fc-2012-02) are summaries of one way to do it.

Comment: To deal with area you need to use some limit based definition of area which mostly uses integrals. The same goes for arc-length also.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Though in cases where geometry is introduced before calculus, one of length or area may be considered a primitive notion. Most often the curve length, for example that's how the measure of an angle is usually defined.

Comment: @dxiv: I  prefer to make following assumptions for a beginner: an arc of a circle has a well defined length, a sector of a circle has a well defined area and finally if $A$ is area of a sector of circle of radius $R$ and $L$ is length of corresponding arc then $A=RL/2$. With these assumptions one may prove the limit in question.